# Handling react context when an error boundary occur

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-error-boundary

I have a component providing a context (=provider) and some children components are consuming the context.

My provider also wraps an ErrorBoundary React component in case of a children crash. From there, if an error happens, the ErrorBoundary React component is updating some values in my context.

But it looks like the value is not update and I don't know why.

Here how my code looks like:

```
const MyContext = React.createContext<{
    state: FsState;
    setState: Dispatch<SetStateAction<FsState>> | null;
}>({ state: { ...initState }, setState: null });
```

```
    const [state, setState] = useState({ ...initState });
    const handleError = (error: Error): void => {
        setState({
            ...state,
            status: {
                ...state.status,
                hasError: !!error
            }
        });
    };
    return (
        <MyContext.Provider value={{ state, setState }}>
            <ErrorBoundary
                onError={handleError}
            >
                {children}
            </ErrorBoundary>
        </MyContext.Provider>
    );
```

ErrorBoundary component:

```
class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { error: null, errorInfo: null };
    }

    componentDidCatch(error: Error, errorInfo: ErrorInfo): void {
        this.props.onError(error);
        this.setState({
            error,
            errorInfo
        });
    }

    render(): React.ReactNode {
        const { error, errorInfo } = this.state;
        const { children } = this.props;
        if (errorInfo) {
            return (
                <>
                    <div
                    >
                        <h1>
                            Something went wrong.
                        </h1>
                    </div>
                    <div>{children}</div>
                </>
            );
        }

        return children;
    }
}
```

And a child component (of my Provider + ErrorBoundary)

```
export const ChildElement = () => {
  const {
    state: { status },
  } = useContext(MyContext);
  if (status.hasError) {
    return <div>I crashed but I'm in safe mode</div>;
  }
  throw new Error("test test"); // trigger an error
  return <div>I'll never work</div>;
};
```

I never enter inside the `if loop` despite the fact that when debugging, the `componentDidCatch` is correctly triggered.

Comment: That is weird and most likely the problem is in the code you have not shared (`initialState?`). I've made a [playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zyw1tc?file=MyContext.js) and everything seems fine there

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your playground @Shlang, I found the issue.

This was indeed something deeper. I have another child component having a `useEffect` and using `setState` as well to update some other values.

The thing was, it was overriding the `hasError:true` back to `hasError:false` because for some asynchronous reason, it was executed after the error is caught by the ErrorBoundary.

I did a workaround by moving the `hasError` attribute in another `useState` hook.

Thank you !